# Toggle CSS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, overflow

```
$('.work').click(function(e){
    $('.information-overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.work-overlay').fadeToggle();
    $('body').toggleClass('overflow');
    e.preventDefault();

});

$('.information').click(function(e){
    $('.work-overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.information-overlay').fadeToggle();
    $('body').toggleClass('overflow');
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

I've got the following code that toggles an overlay, when `.information` is clicked and also toggles between `overflow:hidden` with `toggleClass`.

However, if I click `.work` and THEN `.information`, it breaks the `toggleClass`.

Comment: Create class with required elements and try `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 5):

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

[JQUERY CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Or to toggle

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("body").toggleClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

to add toggle functionality use http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

**css**

```
.b_overflow { overflow:hidden; }'
```

**js**

```
$('body').toggleClass('b_overflow');
```

updated after OP's comment

```
$('.work').click(function(e){
    $('.information-overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.work-overlay').fadeToggle();
    if($(this).css('display') =='block'){
        $(this).css('overflow','scroll');
    }else{
        $(this).css('overflow','hidden');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: But what happens when I want toggle *back*? I need the CSS to change with the toggle.

Comment: @tmyie then you perform two toggles.

Comment: Thanks that works, but it's created a new problem (updated question). If I click between `.work` and `.information`, it breaks the `toggleClass` (because they both feature a `toggleClass`).

Comment: If `.work-overlay` or `.information-overlay` has the CSS property `display:block`, add `overflow:scroll;` to body. If not, don't. Could that solve the problem? (Not sure how to do that with jQuery or JS)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code:

```
$("body").toggleClass("hidden");
```

And then create a class in your css:

```
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will world

```
#("body,html").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

the above solutions are perfect but toggling away body overflow bar will create a little lag on the website since page width will have difference.

Comment: Thanks that works, but it's created a new problem (updated question). If I click between .work and .information, it breaks the toggleClass (because they both feature a toggleClass).

Answer (score -1):

Use `$('body').toggleClass('overflow-hidden')` to toggle a CSS class with the corresponding CSS styles